# Why SqlDependency.OnChange is not being fired?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, signalr, sqldependency

After struggling with this issue from past 3 day, finally I'm putting my problem here.

I'm trying to build a real time application using SignalR and SqlDependency. Apparently, SQLDependency is not working. However, my SignalR is working fine as I've tried many functions that do not require Database interactions.

Below is my code. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/883702/real-time-notifications-using-signalr-and-sql-depe) is I'm taking reference from.

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    NotificationHub objNotificationHub;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQL"];
        // SQL Command Text
        string commandText = "SELECT status From tableTask";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);    
            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
            command.ExecuteReader().Dispose();
            objNotificationHub = new NotificationHub();
        }
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            objNotificationHub.SendNotifications();
        }
    }
}
```

**NotificationHub.cs (SignalR Hub Class)**

```
[HubMethodName("sendNotifications")]
public void SendNotifications()
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    context.Clients.All.recieveNotification("asbc");
}
```

> My SqlDependency.OnChange event i.e. dependency_OnChange is not firing
>   on database update.

I've tried all the methods like granting permissions

> ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET ENABLE_BROKER

and many others like this.
But no success.

Could there be anything that I'm missing. Also, is there any way to check if my code is communicating with SQL Server?

TIA

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You are not executing your command, and that is needed to get notification:

```
SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
string commandText = "SELECT status From dbo.tableTask"; // don't forget schema here
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);    
    command.ExecuteReader().Dispose();
    objNotificationHub = new NotificationHub();
}
```

Ensure that you understand how those dependencies work (for example - after you receive one notification - you need to re-register to get subsequent). Or better, use some wrapper library, like [this](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener) one.

You can test it with this simple example:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var cs = "connection string";        
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select ErrorCode from dbo.Error", connection);
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        dependency.OnChange += OnChange;
        SqlDependency.Start(cs);
        command.ExecuteReader().Dispose();                
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Info);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Evk. I just did that. Unfortunately, no success. TBH, I did that earlier too. But it wasn't working to. Nevertheless, I just wanna know what do you mean by this "you need to re-register to get subsequent". How can I do this in current code?

Comment: I verified that it works before posting, so it should work unless there are other problems. As for reregistering - you just need to execute all this once again (create command, create dependency, execute) after you get one notifcation. First create simple console application and ensure that all works there, without signalr.

Comment: Evk, I've tried one console application as well but I didn't work too. Database changes are not reflecting on code side. Event is not being fired. I've read this nice article 
https://hendrikbulens.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/c-firing-code-after-database-changes-with-sqldependency-it/comment-page-1/#comment-355

Comment: Then post code of that console application (minimum needed to reproduce) and we will figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: @MukeshKumar I see you use "SELECT status From tableTask" as command text. How do you trigger new notification, with what statement? insert\update, which columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140094/discussion-between-mukesh-kumar-and-evk).

Comment: @MukeshKumar I suspect you forgot schema - should be "SELECT status From dbo.tableTask"